# Python loop statements

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have been working on a program for my homework:
Write a program for a car salesperson who works a five day week. The program should prompt for how many cars were sold on each day and then prompt for the selling price of each car (if any) on that day. After the data for all five days have been entered, the program should report the total number of cars sold and the total sales for the period. See example output. NOTE: duplicate the currency format shown for the total sales,

Example Output
How many cars were sold on day 1? 1
Selling price of car 1? 30000
How many cars were sold on day 2? 2
Selling price of car 1? 35000
Selling price of car 2? 45000
How many cars were sold on day 3? 0
How many cars were sold on day 4? 1
Selling price of car 1? 30000
How many cars were sold on day 5? 0
You sold 4 cars for total sales of $140,000.00

I do have some code that I have worked on but I am stuck. I can figure out how to get the program to prompt the user for how many cars were sold on day 2 and so on. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code, I am also taking a basic python course so I am new to this!!

```
    def main () :

   cars_sold = []
   num_days = int(input('How many days do you have sales?'))

   for count in range(1, num_days + 1):
       cars = int(input('How many cars were sold on day?' + \
                        str(count) + ' '))

   while (cars != cars_sold):
    for count in range(1, cars + 1):
        cars_sold = int(input('Selling price of car' ' ' + \
                           str(count) + ' '))
```

main ()

Answer (score 0):

For this you would want to use nested for loop to prompt for each car entered.

```
def main():
    cars_sold = 0
    total = 0
    num_days = int(input('How many days do you have sales? '))

    # for each day
    for i in range(1, num_days + 1):
        num_cars = int(input('How many cars were sold on day {0}? '.format(i)))
        cars_sold += num_cars

        # for each car of each day
        for j in range(1, num_cars + 1):
            price = int(input('Selling price of car {0}? '.format(j)))
            total += price

    # Output number of cars and total sales with $ and comma format to 2 decimal places
    print('You sold {0} cars for total sales of ${1:,.2f}'.format(cars_sold, total))

# Output
>>> main()
How many days do you have sales? 5
How many cars were sold on day 1? 1
Selling price of car 1? 30000
How many cars were sold on day 2? 2
Selling price of car 1? 35000
Selling price of car 2? 45000
How many cars were sold on day 3? 0
How many cars were sold on day 4? 1
Selling price of car 1? 30000
How many cars were sold on day 5? 0
You sold 4 cars for total sales of $140,000.00
```